# Pass a param to a json in spock test

Tags: json, parameter-passing, spock

I am working with the next json in a spock test, where the podCastId is a dynamic value:

```
private buildPodCast(long podCastId) {
        String jsonString = '''
        {
          "id": ${podCastId},
          "lang": "en",
          "updated": "2019-04-03T19:48:29Z",
          "premium": false,
          "headline": "The Lowe Post",
          "description": "ESPN's Zach Lowe talks to various basketball people about various basketball things.",
          "thumbnails": {
            "light": {
              "href": "http://a.espncdn.com/i/espn/networks_shows/radio/crops/500/the_lowe_post.png",
              "width": 500,
              "height": 500
            }
          }
        }
        '''
        return JsonUtilKt.transformToJsonNode(jsonString)
    }
```

My problem is that I have to pass the podCastId param in the id value,but in the way that is now, the json is not taking the param value.

I am struggling with this test, any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used the string concatenation:

```
private buildPodCast(long podCastId) {
        String jsonString = '''
        {
          "id": ''' + podCastId + ''',
          "lang": "en",
          "updated": "2019-04-03T19:48:29Z",
          "premium": false,
          "headline": "The Lowe Post",
          "description": "ESPN's Zach Lowe talks to various basketball people about various basketball things.",
          "thumbnails": {
            "light": {
              "href": "http://a.espncdn.com/i/espn/networks_shows/radio/crops/500/the_lowe_post.png",
              "width": 500,
              "height": 500
            }
          }
        }
        '''
        return JsonUtilKt.transformToJsonNode(jsonString)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following piece of code works fine as well - no need for concatenation, [string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation) (which works for `"""` and doesn't for `'''`) does the job:

```
def buildPodCast(long podCastId) {
"""
{
    "id": ${podCastId},
    "lang": "en",
    "updated": "2019-04-03T19:48:29Z",
    "premium": false,
    "headline": "The Lowe Post",
    "description": "ESPN's Zach Lowe talks to various basketball people about various basketball things.",
    "thumbnails": {
        "light": {
            "href": "http://a.espncdn.com/i/espn/networks_shows/radio/crops/500/the_lowe_post.png",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        }
    }
}
"""
}
buildPodCast(2)
```

Comment: You should explain the difference between `'''` and `"""` in Groovy then it would be more helpful.

Comment: @rasilvap: I suggest to un-accept your own answer and accept this one instead. This is the correct solution, yours is a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex!!